# Css using multiple stylesheets issue

Tags: html, css

In simple html page,we can use something like this:

```
<style type="text/css">
a {text-decoration:none;}
 a { color: inherit; } 
/*----------Text Styles----------*/
.ws72 {font-size: 88px;}
.ws74 {font-size: 93px;}

.wpmd {font-size: 13px;font-family: Arial,Helvetica,Sans-Serif;font-style: normal;font-weight: normal;}
/*----------Para Styles----------*/
DIV,UL,OL /* Left */
{
 margin-top: 0px;
 margin-bottom: 0px;
}
</style>
```

With classess like:

```
<div>
 <font class="ws72" >
      </div>
```

And another one like:

```
<div class="wpmd">
      <div>
```

That's all with same page css and now how can i use something like:

```
<link href="example.com/better.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">  for class .ws72
```

and like:

```
<link href="example.com/best.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
for .wpmd
```

Comment: You cannot specify that a linked stylesheet applies to one class only. Or maybe I just don't understand what you're asking.

Comment: You're not asking a question.

Comment: @GolezTrol  you are correct that it can't be specified to particular,but how can i assign <div>
 <font class="ws72" >
      </div> to use external stylesheet like <link href="example.com/better.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

Comment: @SteynvanEsveld then what it is?

Comment: @Aniltiwari It's more like a comment. What is it that you want to reach? I can't find a question mark anywhere in your text. Why would you ever want to use multiple css files for something like this? You can just make a style.css and put it all in there?

Comment: @SteynvanEsveld ok dear.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you're using old html tag like `<font>` which is deprecated to use nowadays. So, I recommend you not to use that tag.

And to your question you don't need to separate the stylesheets but you can add multiple style rules in your single stylesheet and if the page has one class then your stylesheet will use that and same thing applies for other pages.

Comment: put all your style rules in a single stylesheet and you're there.

Comment: I understanded what you say,to merge all in one,that's ok but How to specify <div>
 <font class="ws72" >
      </div> to use external stylesheet like: <link href="example.com/best.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

Answer (score 0):

You can use all types at the same time. 
Just remember that it will execute with different priority according to css selectors weigth. Read about it at [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity),
or at [Smashingmagazine](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2007/07/css-specificity-things-you-should-know/) (with cool pictures).